# How to zero unused memory to reduce VM snapshot size

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

In Linux, how can I zero-out freed memory pages to reduce the size of VM
snapshots?

Non-zeroed memory is stored in the snapshot even if that memory has been freed
and is no longer used. For example, memory pages freed from the filesystem cache
with

```
 sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

are needlessly stored in the snapshot because they haven't been zeroed.

**Update** A really horrible solution that appears to work is to malloc+memset memory in a loop until the OOM killer kicks in. This reduces the size of one VM snapshot I tested from about 800MB to about 400MB.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: (deleted answer since after the edit, it seems I misunderstood what you really wanted)

Comment: I think this isn't even possible. Linux has a single COW zero page that it returns on new allocation, and that it copies upon the first write access (creating a page full of zeroes, but that's technically not a zero page any more). You _could_ thus zero out all physical memory (in theory) by allocating a big amount of memory and writing `'\0'` to the beginning of every page, but these will afterwards be pages containing data (zeroes, as it happens), not zero pages. And if you free those again, they'll be the same as the non-zero freed pages you had anyway -- only they'll contain zeroes.

Comment: Though you might try doing this (allocated a lot of memory, and make it physically zeroed), and then `MADV_MERGEABLE` on the whole lot. Maybe kernel samepage merging will do the trick. Note that this isn't precisely a free operation (CPU-wise).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will free up disk cache, then alloc&memset the amount of free memory (minus 32MB, as headroom to avoid hitting swap) using dd. Will temporarily make the VM un-CoW memory in case of for example KSM, but will leave (unallocated) memory blocks filled with zeroes, which can then be shared/deduped with other VMs (with KSM) or easily be compressed.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
memfree=$(free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print $4-32}')
if [ $memfree -gt 0 ]; then
        dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=${memfree}M count=1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of a virtual machine:

1. Log into the virtual machine; open a terminal and type

   ```
   cd /home/

   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=foo bs=4096

   sudo rm foo
   ```
2. Shut down the virtual machine, enter the VmWare/VmPlayer menu and go to

   vmware -> virtual machine settings -> HD -> utilities -> compact

   and compact the virtual machine

If you want to further reduce the size, use 7-zip. For example, on Linux, you can type:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on archive.7z directory
```

Comment: This affects cust the virtual hard disk, not the virtual RAM. The question is about snapshots, which include hard disk data as well as RAM data.